# Xamarin Test Recorder - How to Use with iOS App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I'm using Xamarin Forms v2.0 with Visual Studio 2015 using a Macbook as a build agent. I'm evaluating Xamarin Test Recorder as a means of creating UI Tests to be uploaded to Test Cloud.

Test recorder runs on a Mac and requires the user to select a device (or simulator) and an app to test on the device.

I selected the iPhone simulator that is running on the Mac but am suck at the next step - select an app.

I'm guessing I must provide an IPA and that the IPA must be on the Mac somewhere as the Xamarin build agent built it there but I can't find it.

The very limited documentation and videos are of no help as they mainly focus on Android apps which are much easier to package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the VS & Xamarin Mac Agent, those build products, including the `.app`, will be located within the build cache (assuming it has not been flushed):

```
~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds
```

The contents of the caches' `builds` directory are safe to delete, so if you can not find which directory, delete it, rebuild your app and recheck the directory...

Note: As Steve pointed out in the comments, Test Recorder is looking for an `.app` to be selected and not the `.ipa`

Comment: Spot on with the folder name. The other thing I did wrong was look for a IPA file but it was the APP that was required by Test Recorder. Hopefully this will all be documented at some point.